# Internet Explorer window in Qt?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, qt, activeqt

Is there a way to show an Internet Explorer instance/frame inside a [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)) Widget? I need to show a web page in my application (just show, no need for interaction), and while I read about [WebKit for Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#Ports), I'd like to know if there is another way without it, since I'm trying to keep the application as small as possible, and it would make me very unhappy to include such a large library (and nobody wants that, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the [commercial edition of Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/commercialeditions.html) and then, you can use [ActiveQt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/activeqt.html).

Comment: It's also available in the Open Source versions. Says so at the bottom of the page you linked to.

Comment: On the first page, it says that it isn't. :) Maybe it's available since Qt 4.5 (since the source code is now open).

Answer (score -1):

Your windows has 10GiB+  already in windows/system/. I think using WebKit is better investment than making your app depend on such old component as the IE frame... Just my 2c.